# How to move different shapes with MouseListener

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a program that paints different shapes that I put in the ArrayList, it works fine to iterate with shapes to paint them but my methods for moving them doesn't work. Is it something wrong with my move() method?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MyShapes extends JPanel {
private Point2D.Float position;

private final DifferentShapes[] shapes = new DifferentShapes[]{new Circle(), new Triangle(), new Square()};

MovingAdapter ma = new MovingAdapter();

    public MyShapes() {
        addMouseMotionListener(ma);
        addMouseListener(ma);
    }

    interface DifferentShapes {
        void paint(Graphics2D graphics);
        boolean contains(int x, int y);
        void move(int dx, int dy);
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (DifferentShapes shape : this.shapes) {
        shape.paint(graphics);
    }
}
```

class MovingAdapter

```
  public  class MovingAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        final int dx = e.getX() - x;
        final int dy = e.getY() - y;

        for (DifferentShapes shape : shapes) {
            if (shape.contains(x, y)) {
                shape.move(dx, dy);
            }
        }
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Shapes World");
    MyShapes m = new MyShapes();
    m.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    frame.add(m);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

class Circle

```
 class Circle implements MyShapes.DifferentShapes {

public Circle() {
}
public static Ellipse2D.Float myCr = new Ellipse2D.Float(10,10, 100, 100);

public void paint(Graphics2D graphics) {
    Graphics2D circle = (Graphics2D) graphics;

    circle.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    circle.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    circle.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 117));
    circle.fill(myCr);
}
@Override
public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    if (myCr.contains(x, y)) {
    }
    return true;
}
public void move(int dx, int dy) {
    myCr.x += dx;
    myCr.y += dy;
}

}
```

When I use regular if statement it works fine but not in the for loop and my move() method

Comment: Heya mate. It's difficult to tell what is going on with your code when you have 3 different classes combined into the same file. I would first recommend refactoring your code to separate out your classes from each other and then see what is not working as expected. Use standard debugging practices to check the values passed into the method/loop and see if they are as you expect.

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: In the `mousePressed` logic you should identify the object that has been clicked. Then in the `mouseDragged` you move that object and repaint the panel. In the `mouseReleased` you then reset the clicked object variable to null.

Comment: Is it also with for-loop ? Indentify the object?

Comment: Yes you need the for loop to identify the object. The point is you only execute this loop once when the mouse is pressed. Then when you drag you don't need to repeat the search. The mousePressed is also where you would invoke the logic from the suggestion in your last posting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60994387/131872

Comment: aha ok, now I understand, I'll try that

Comment: do you know any example I can look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is right and you are correctly changing the coordinates. You just need to call `repaint()` in order to make the the changes display.

```java
if (shape.contains(x, y)) {
   shape.move(dx, dy);
   repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double x = 0, y = 0, dx = 0, dy = 0;
for(Node n: selectedList)
{
    x += n.getLayoutX();
    y += n.getLayoutY();
}
dx = e.getX() - x / selectedList.size();
dy = e.getY() - y / selectedList.size();
for (Node n : selectedList)
{
    n.setTranslateX(dx);
    n.setTranslateY(dy);
}
```

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't see how your code is related to the question. Can you [edit] your answer and explain how your code solves the question? Have you looked at [Answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) in the [help]?